# How do I make the active text box in PowerPoint 2007 display an active(blinking) cursor when in slideshow mode?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm not very experienced with PowerPoint. I have created the active textbox using the developer tab.

However, I want the text entry cursor to be automatically active for data entry when in the slideshow mode (without the user having to click inside the textbox to activate it). Is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a good deal of serious programming (not scripting), it might be possible.

But if it is all for show, why don't you use an animated GIF or a video of a blinking cursor inside a box?

Comment: I'm trying to make the text box interactive as it is part of a test (the test uses multiple screens). I wanted the textbox to be active in slideshow mode as the user will not be able to click inside the box to activate it (due to time constraints)